# Handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-rds

I am trying to have a stable connection to a MySQL database hosted on Amazon Web Services. Periodically when starting the application, I will get the exception:

*Handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format*

This is a WinForm C# application using MySQL.Data.dll V6.9.9

Here is my code for connecting:

```
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(m_connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to database");
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                validConnectionFound = false;
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to Database. Check your network connection and try again", "Database connection Not Found");
            }
            catch (CryptographicException ex)
            {
                validConnectionFound = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Cryptographic Exception: " + ex.Message);
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                validConnectionFound = false;
                DebugTrace.TraceWrite(m_defaultTraceSource, TraceEventType.Error, "Incorrect certificate. Please update security certificate. Exception: " + ex.Message);
                MessageBox.Show("IO Exception: " + ex.Message);
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
```

My connection string is in the following format:

```
"user id=user;password=1234;server=amazonserver.com;database=myDatabase;convertzerodatetime=True;port=3306;sslmode=VerifyCA"
```

I have tried both wireless and wired connections, changing the SSL mode required (VerifyCA, Required, VerifyFull, None), and adding Amazons CA to my computers trusted root certificates.

Any insight on why I am getting this exception is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was not code related. After sniffing packets with Wireshark, I found the problem was with a faulty network switch losing packets.